# PHP Countdown SQL Rows from Total Rows to 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I couldn't quite find what I was look for by googling or searching stackoverflow, so I'm just gonna ask it.

```
$reply_sql = mysqli_query($successconnect, "SELECT * FROM replies WHERE reply_thread = '" . $reply_thread_id . "' ORDER BY reply_date DESC LIMIT $cur, $max");
$numbb = ((20 - (20 * $page)) * -1);
while($reply_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reply_sql)) {
$numbb++;
```

This will result in each reply row counting from 1 up to the total amount of rows. That is all fine if I want my replies to order ASC.

I want it to go from total amount of rows down to 0. I imagine this is all math, but I'm really bad at it. And maybe there's an easier way to do this.

```
$numbb--;
```

This I know about, but I tried many variations of $numbb and couldn't quite figure out a way to make for instance:

```
23 (Total Replies) 1 (Page 1) makes it count from 23 down to 3
23 (Total Replies) 2 (Page 2) makes it count from 3 down to 1
```

Comment: Please show your SQL statement.

Comment: @toonice Completely unnecessary, but added.

Comment: Why not order your records by the message's primary key or another field with sequential properties using SQL?  You can use a PHP `if` statement to construct your SQL with `DESC` or `ASC` being added as appropriate.

Comment: @toonice This is for each individual thread, so the primary key would not match the amount of rows for each thread.

Comment: The messages of a thread would presumably arrive in the table `replies` one after the other.  Even after removal of nonthread messages the primary key values (and possibly other values) should still occur one after the other.  As such, ordering the thread's list by primary key (or by another sequential field) should be effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while of trying different combinations, but I had to move around the original code with 23 or replycount in mind to get the result I need.

```
$numbb = ((($replycount + 20) - (20 * $page)) + 1);
while($reply_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reply_sql)) {
$numbb--;
```

23 + 20 = 43 - 20 * 1 = 23 + 1 = 24 which $numbb shows as 23 with the first row.
And then 23 + 20 = 43 - 20 * 2 = 3 + 1 = 4 which shows as 3 on page 2.